# Recurring payment, hybrid app and website, what's the right way with Paypal?

Tags: cordova, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-subscriptions

I'm developing a project which includes a web portal, an Apache Cordova app developed with Intel XDK for Android, iOS and Windows Phone 8.

I need my customer subscribes a monthly payment and receives automatically an invoice.

I need to link customer's payments with my web site so, if he stops payments, I suspend his account.

Since Paypal has a lot of feature and API, which account and which API I have to use to get this result?

Comment: You should provide detailed information on the feature the user gets for that payment. Apple will not allow you to use other payment methods than the inApp-Purchase via your Apple-ID. If they would do so, they would resign on their 30%.

Comment: My customer can start the monthly payment on the website.
It's not mandatory that apps handle payments if they are automatic.

Comment: I'm waiting for you, thaks!